# Wrong ScrollView insets when Adjust Scroll View Insets is set to YES in storyboard only

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uistoryboard

Problem is with displaying in storyboard only the UIScrollView in UIViewController:

[image]

I set on this ViewController "Adjust Scroll View Insets" to YES and this is the result. I expected it to behave similar when there is UITableView or UICollectionView in the UIViewController but not.

It seems that "Adjust Scroll View Insets" option don't make any visible change in storyboard. During runtime everything is positioned right so the proper inset is added to the top of the contentView of the scrollView.

Why there is only problem during design time in storyboard? Does somebody know? Am I doing something wrong? My UIViewController is inside UINavigationController which has also set "Adjust Scroll View Insets" to YES. When I put instead UITableView to this controller it seems that storyboard know how to calculate and adjust Insets in ScrollView of the table. So how to achieve the same results in just normal UIScrollView?

I know how to make it work in code but I'm interested in storyboard solution only.

Comment: "Adjust Scroll View Insets" makes difference at run time. Checking unchecking do not update the insets in IB.

Comment: But when Table view instead of scroll view is inside the view controller then checking and unchecking this option is visible in IB.

Comment: Just a side note, If you put a view behind the same tableview, you might notice that it looses this inset adjusting feature at storyboard level. Thats how IB is.